# Wget over SSL gives: Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: linux, ssl, centos, wget

This may be a similar post to what others have mentioned but wget with --no-check-certificate returns "Unable to establish SSL connection"

```
wget https://example.com/xyz
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Same with curl.

Any way to fix it ?

Comment: did you tried `--check-no-certificate`.

Comment: Does it work in the browser? Maybe the website is not available over https? Also, please try to find a proper solution before following @Viren's advice...

Comment: What switches are you using? Set the verbose on to see further details.

Comment: I got it to work on my macbook using: `curl -s --insecure https://example.com/xyz`. How can I do it on CentOS or RHEL ?

Comment: SSL problems depend both on the server and client side. Without more information about the server (URL) and client (`wget --version`) it is impossible to say what the real problem is and how to fix it. A typical cause of such problems is using some old version which does not support SNI against a site which needs SNI (like all of cloudflare free ssl). And in this case disabling certificate validation will not help.

Comment: I am using `GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.`

Comment: wget has support for SNI since 1.14 only, so this might be the problem. You can check the URL with [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and see if it requires SNI.

Comment: use wget -vv (very verbosity)  and show message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have install 1.16 but I am not sure how to use SNI. 
@abkrim -vv only gives `Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: SNI does not need to be enabled, i.e. is implicit. If you need more help please see my comment which information are needed for both client and server and add **all** of these to your question in **full detail**.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My server is behind firewall so the ssllabs link isn't working. Any other way to post information you need ?

Comment: You could use tools like [sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) or my [analyze-ssl.pl](https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl) to get more detailed information about the server. Also packet capture would help and look for errors in the servers log files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try `wget --no-check-certificate https://example.com/xyz`

Comment: Does not work for me :-(

Comment: same command not working for me wget --version 1.14

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-10-46-167-xx DATA]$ wget --no-check-certificate https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
--2023-06-14 07:31:09--  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz

Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... 209.51.188.20, 2001:470:142:3::b
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|209.51.188.20|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: @RajamohanRajendran It works for me:  wget --no-check-certificate ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
--2023-06-14 12:04:24--  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)... ...
Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (ftp.gnu.org)|209.51.188.20|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5059591 (4.8M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘wget-latest.tar.gz’

wget-latest.tar.gz            100%[=...=>]   4.83M  2.87MB/s    in 1.7s

2023-06-14 12:04:26 (2.87 MB/s) - ‘wget-latest.tar.gz’ saved [5059591/5059591]

Comment: @RajamohanRajendran I suggest you update your wget and retry. wget version 1.14 you are using is 11 years old! https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2012-08/msg00002.html